# Don't apply color in section of Annexes

Tags: color, sections-paragraphs

I create a specific color font for my sections and subsections.

```
\chapterfont{\color{blue}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{purple}}  % sets colour of sections
\subsectionfont{\color{magenta}}  % sets colour of subsections
\subsubsectionfont{\color{cyan}}  % sets colour of subsections
\paragraphfont{\color{teal}}  % sets colour of paragraph
```

But in my Annexes I don't like to color sections.

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Please always post _complete_ documents showing the problem and needed packages. _none_ of the commands in your fragment are defined in latex unless we guess which packages you have used.  (I can't guess all of them)  That said can't you just go \chapterfont{\color{black}} at the start of your appendix section

Comment: @DavidCarlisle nice idea thanks solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that I have no idea where this command is defined, it appears in comments that you can go:

```
\chapterfont{\color{black}}
```

at the start of your appendix section

Comment: The command is defined in my main.tex file and 
Yes, at the start of appendix.tex file I add 
`\chapterfont{\color{black}}   
\sectionfont{\color{black}}` 
as you said and it okay thanks to you